# how to find image inside an image that is smaller

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

Using emgucv c#...

I want to find an image of an object that is inside another image.

To test my code I crop the image I am looking for in the original image and save it as a Template.jpg.

I then use this routine which does find the template image inside the original image:

```
private Point Detect_object(
    Image<Gray, Byte> Area_Image,
    Image<Gray, Byte> image_object )
{
    //Work out padding array size
    Point dftSize = new Point( Area_Image.Width + ( image_object.Width * 2 ), Area_Image.Height + ( image_object.Height * 2 ) );
    //Pad the Array with zeros
    using ( var pad_array = new Image<Gray, Byte>( dftSize.X, dftSize.Y ) )
    {
        //copy centre
        pad_array.ROI = new Rectangle( image_object.Width, image_object.Height, Area_Image.Width, Area_Image.Height );
        CvInvoke.cvCopy( Area_Image, pad_array, IntPtr.Zero );

        pad_array.ROI = ( new Rectangle( 0, 0, dftSize.X, dftSize.Y ) );

        //Match Template
        using ( var result_Matrix = pad_array.MatchTemplate( image_object, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed ) )
        {
            Point[] MAX_Loc, Min_Loc;
            double[] min, max;
            //Limit ROI to look for Match

            result_Matrix.ROI = new Rectangle( image_object.Width, image_object.Height, Area_Image.Width - image_object.Width, Area_Image.Height - image_object.Height );

            result_Matrix.MinMax( out min, out max, out Min_Loc, out MAX_Loc );

            _location = new Point( ( MAX_Loc[ 0 ].X ), ( MAX_Loc[ 0 ].Y ) );
            var Results = result_Matrix.Convert<Gray, Double>();
            return _location;
        }
    }
}
```

and i call this with:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("d:\\original.jpg");
Image<Gray, Byte> My_Image_Gray = My_Image.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
Image<Gray, Byte> Template = new Image<Gray, Byte>("d:\\template.jpg");
var pt = Detect_object( My_Image_Gray, Template );
My_Image.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(pt.X, pt.Y), 10), new Bgr(0, 0, 255));
My_Image.Save("D:\\result.jpg");
```

Now this works fine.

So, I thought if I had a bunch of templates at different angles and lighting etc I could attempt to do my own classifier (somehow -  I need to investigate how)

But first, I thought lets reduce the size of the original image and rerun the code.

This time it did not find the template.

So is template matching done on size as well?  If so, what other techniques can I explore?

thanks

Comment: The template matching library you're using is doing a simple array search using statistics to find a match. It won't handle resized or rotated images. For that you'd need some sort of object recognition / machine vision.

Comment: @RogerN Thanks. Such was my suspicion :)